# Accessing jQuery created element's child(ren)

Tags: jquery

I create an element in jQuery

```
var select = $('<ul />');
```

I append li-s and a-s to it. Afterwards I want to access created element's child, let's say a link.

I cannot do select.find('a'). How can I access it?

I dont want to append select first and than use it's class or id to look for it in HTML, I need to do it before I append element to HTML.

Thanks!

EDIT: Always check your element AFTER you have created them :P Thank you, problem solved. I wasted 2 hrs to understand what i do wrong, now when I tried to copy you the code, i found the mistake. Thanks you :D

Comment: Why can't you do `select.find('a')`? That's exactly what you should do.

Comment: It returns undefined :) Because select hasn't been appended into document yet. When I append it to HTML, it works perfectly.

Comment: No, it would work just fine even before being appended, you must have some other error. Post the rest of your code. Edit: Seems you found the error.

Answer (score 3):

This works perfectly

```
$('<ul/>').append('<li><a id="link"/></li>').find('a');
```

Try to post the full code, there must be some other kind of mistake in it :)